# Posting json data using RestSharp and OAuth

Tags: json, post, oauth, restsharp

I am trying to make a basic Rest call using RestSharp by implementing OAuth. I succeeded to make Get but I don't know how to send the json data. I am using DotNetAuth to implement OAtuh. here is my GET method.

```
var http = new Http { Url = new Uri("http://localhost/rest/api/getproj") };

http.ApplyAccessTokenToHeader(provider, myCredentials, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, "GET");
var response = http.Get();
```

provider is an instance of OAuth1aProviderDefinition in DotNetAuth.OAuth1a

I know that it maybe needs to invoke http.Post() but how do you send the json data? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem here is the solution

```
 http.RequestBody = jsonData;
 http.RequestContentType = "application/json";
 var response = http.Post();
```